# Is there an analogue of the macOS program security for the Debian?

Tags: debian, security, macos

As an macOS user, I can use a [security](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/security/) to store symmetric keys. I can add such a key to a chain and if I don’t specify which chain, the default chain will be used:

```
security add-generic-password -s "$SERVICE_NAME" -a "$ACCOUNT_NAME" -w "$PASSWORD_VALUE" -T ''
```

In my case, the following chain was used:

```
$ security default-keychain
  "/Users/stanley/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
```

As it turned out, this chain is protected by a password from the operating system user account. I found it very convenient to use one user confirmation to read some passwords. Instead of using separate passwords for each database.

For example, I once saved the [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/) database password in such a chain and can only access it by confirming that I am a user of the operating system account:

```
security find-generic-password -w -s common -a keepass \
 | /Applications/KeePassXC.app/Contents/MacOS/KeePassXC --pw-stdin "${PATH_TO_KDBX_DB}"
```

My question is - is there an analogue [security](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/security/) for the Debian? I understand how to make my own circuit in, for example, a [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/) and manually protect it with the same password as the password for the OS account. But it is important for me to have access to the chain for confirming access to the OS account. This is what happens, for example, when executing a command through `sudo`.